# Is there a way to automatically highlight changes made in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple people that is reviewing data in google sheets and they might need to make changes to a cell. Is there a way to automatically highlight a cell when someone makes a change? I don't need to know who made it, just that the cell has changed, compared to a certain point in time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found this code and modified for myself sow whenever anybody makes a change to any cell it will highlight in yellow. Then you can write a script that reset all the colors once per day, week, month depending on sheet activity.

```
function onEdit() {



var sheetsToWatch = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4', 'Sheet5', 'etc.'];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var sheetName = sheet.getName();
var matchFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
if (!matchFound) return;

var rowColLabel = 
sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()).setBackground('#faec15'); // #faec15 
 // set backgorund color in yellow, 
  // you can do any color 

  }
```

Comment: This worked well for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use on edit (simple or installable) or the on change triggers to run a function that change the cell formatting, like applying a color to the cell background.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events